# In a Spanner database can I change existing foreign keys for interleaving relationship?

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I am creating a script to create a Spanner database, I have some one-to-many relationships, and I would like to use foreign keys as other databases. if in the future I decide to use interleaving relationships, can I change the existing foreign keys for interleaving?

CREATE TABLE Singers
(
SingerId  INT64 NOT NULL,
FirstName STRING(1024),
LastName  STRING(1024),
) PRIMARY KEY (SingerId);

CREATE TABLE Albums
(
SingerId   INT64 NOT NULL,
AlbumId    INT64 NOT NULL,
AlbumTitle STRING( MAX),
) PRIMARY KEY (SingerId, AlbumId);

ALTER TABLE Albums
ADD CONSTRAINT Albums_fk FOREIGN KEY (SingerId) REFERENCES Singers (SingerId);

This is my example script, I would like create my database with this script, and modify the relationship in the future after the database creation

Answer (score 1):

Spanner doesn't support interleaving existing tables. You can work around that by making a copy of the "child" table to another table (say child_temp). Drop the existing child then create a new child using the same name and interleave it with the parent. Copy data from child_temp to child then drop child_temp.